# How to use IEnumerable public property?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

```
public class Kuku
{
    private LinkedList<MyClass> m_list;
    public IEnumerable<MyClass> Locations { get { return m_list; } }
}
```

I need to implement in `public class FindAllMyClass`
the method which iterates all `MyClass` objects in `Kuku` - I don't know how do I use `Locations` property  from `Kuku`.

Should I define IEnumerable Locations or just make LinkedList m_list to be public property?

Should I define `IEnumerable<MyClass> Locations` or just make `LinkedList<MyClass> m_list` to be a `public` property?

```
public class FindAllMyClass
{
    public void itMethod(Kuku input)
    {
        //This is not correct
        foreach (MyClass c in input.Locations)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is that not correct?  What's the problem?

Comment: Your method signature is wrong, it should have a return type something like `public void itMethod(kuku input)`, other than that your code is fine.

Comment: What Exception/Build error are you getting?

Comment: Why to define IEnumerable Locations and not just make LinkedList m_list to be public property?

Comment: @Yakov: A) Lots of reasons, not the least of which being that you can introduce getter/setter logic without breaking the interface.  As a general rule objects encapsulate data and expose functionality on that data.  B) What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: If you want to loop through the LinkedList items, why access it through the IEnumerable?  The way you have it coded, it looks like your loop will iterate only once regardless of how many items are in the LinkedList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why to define `IEnumerable Locations` and not just make `LinkedList m_list` to be public property?

Several possible reasons:

- What if later you decide you don't want to implement it as a `LinkedList<>` but as a regular `List`?  Or a lazy-loaded collection type?  or an array?
- Exposing the collection as a generic `IEnumerable<T>` allows you to change out the internal implementation later without changing the public contract.
- If you make the collection a property (with `get; set;` accessors) you are allowing clients to add to, remove from, even replace *the entire list*.  Exposing it as `IEnumerable` indicates that the list is *intended* to be read-only (unless you expose `Add` methods somewhere else).

> I don't know how do I use Locations property from Kuku.

Sure you do - you're already doing it in your sample:

```
foreach (MyClass c in input.Locations)
{
}
```

Or you can use Linq to search for or aggregate data from the collection (`foreach` is still appropriate for *updating* the instances.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ to object:

```
input.Locations.Where(x=> x.Property1 == value1 && x.Property2 > value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable` gives you a way to expose a list from your class which has the following properties:

- It is implementation independent - you can change what sort of list you use internally without needing to change everything which uses your class
- It integrates well with `LINQ`, `foreach` and various other language constructs
- It provides a read only view on the list, so no chance of others updating the list (inserting/deleting items)